# How to share contacts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

By using IPhone SDK (on a jail broken iPhone), how can I share a contact (.vcf file) through mail as same as the address book is doing?

Regards,
Prathap.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Address Book Framework reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=Address%20Book)? It allows you to fetch records from the Address Book database. You may have to put this data in vCard format yourself, I don't know if the framework provides this functionality for you.

Comment: Yes, there is no support in the Public API. But as far as I know we can do this by "ABPerson C" reference in MAC. But I'm not sure whether we can do the same in IPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this on the iPhone:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = CFAutorelease(ABAddressBookCreate());
NSArray* contacts = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

Erica Sadun's [ABContactHelper](http://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper) classes come in mighty handy if you want to mess around with the Address Book interface.