# Can an app access contact list

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can an app access the contact list?  If yes what class do I use?  If not, would 4.0 allow that?

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976514/how-to-share-contacts/2427929#2427929

Answer (score 1):

See AddressBook and AddressBookUI frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Have yet to try it, but I think the answer is yes.

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/200-QuickStart/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1